# Setting a specific font using CSS

Tags: css, windows, firefox, fonts, truetype

The Liberation Sans Narrow font is included with many versions of Microsoft Windows.  It is a discrete font, defined by the file `LiberationSansNarrow-Regular.ttf`.

How, in CSS, can this font be specified?  Simply specifying:

```
font-family: "Liberation Sans Narrow";
```

will not work.

Note that specifying:

```
font-family: "Liberation Sans";
```

will work to specify the `Liberation Sans` font, which is defined by a **different** TrueType font file.

I only need the CSS code to work in Firefox.  It is perfectly acceptable (and expected) that it will only work in browsers running on systems that have that specific font installed.

Note that I don't want to approximate Liberation Sans Narrow; I want that specific font to be used due to the clarity of rendering.

I want to specify this font for modifying the chrome within Firefox using userChrome.css.

Comment: download the `webfont kit` from [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/liberation-sans) and include it in your project it will work on all

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how the file has been included in the page.
1) font included through url then the file would have the font name used for it. we need to use the same font name
2) font included locally through the font-face then we need to use the name we mention to that font